# Unity 5 Standard Assets for Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: assets, unity, linux

[Unity recently has released Unity3D Editor for Linux machines.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/unity3d-linux-build) But in its website there is no support for Linux / Ubuntu. As of Unity 5 standard game assets have been removed from the editor itself and should be installed apart.

For installation I should follow these steps:

- http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download?ref=personal
- Additional Downloads
- Standard Assets

But there are only options for Windows and OS X, nothing for Linux. So what should I do? Is it possible to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that article, the link to the download is there.
The link is: [Unity Editor 5.1.0f3 For Linux](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb). It is considered 'experimental'.

> there are only options for Windows and OS X, nothing for Linux

It is because the current build is `experimental` and is not very suitable for game development as there may be game-crashing bugs still.

You will be able to use any platform of standard assets. There is little to no difference between the standard assets for OSX and Windows. It is also available on the [Unity 
asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351).

Referring to [Unity on Linux Release Notes](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/),

> The Unity Editor for Linux is packaged into two types of installers:
>   A .deb package, which can be installed via the Ubuntu Software Center and is expected to work on installations of Ubuntu 12.04 or newer.
>   A platform-agnostic self-extracting shell script, which is designed for other distributions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using Unity3D for Linux.

I installed the Standard Assets by downloading the Window version of the standart assets (.exe), installed it with Wine and then copy the folder resulting from the installation into my Linux Unity folder (by default for me it was /opt/Unity/Editor)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However this Linux version is now full of bugs, though.

Answer (score 0):

Now 2016.09.20, Unity3d 5 for Ubuntu can install `standard assets` from Assets Store inner Unity3d.

Answer (score 0):

You just download unity using the following link,

[Unity 5.1 For Linux](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb)

It will contains standard asset also. Don't forget to select standard assets while installing.